# Selenium based Python Script: Error Selecting and Clicking span element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Hey total newbie to selenium and Python here. I'm sure you guys are going to rip me to shreds for missing a glaringly obvious solution to my problem, but I need YOUR help.

I'm using a python script to automatically upload listings to facebook marketplace found in it's entirety here: https://github.com/GeorgiKeranov/facebook-marketplace-bot

THE PROBLEM:
When the part of the script that selects and clicks a span element runs, the script is unable to find and click the element, eventually ending in the script printing this when the box is for Used - Good condition

ERROR: Timed out waiting for the element with xpath "//span[@dir="auto"][text()="Used – good"]" to load

THE CODE:

In the above context, this line of code is run:

scraper.element_click_by_xpath('//span[@dir="auto"][text()="' + data['Condition'] + '"]')

The function written in the webscraper program looks like this:

```
def element_click_by_xpath(self, xpath, delay = True):
    if delay:
        self.wait_random_time()

    element = self.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)

    try:
        element.click()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

CONCLUSION:

I'm a novice coder and I would really appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

I've tried changing the parameters to run on different drop down boxes with different box names and I'm still drawing blanks.

Any answers or leads to follow would be appreciated.